# Ajax form submitted in jQuery not firing events

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-ajax

I have an ajax form and when I submit the form via jQuery the event handlers are not triggered.  Can anyone perhaps spot the error of my way?

**index.cshtml**

```
//abbreviated
@Html.Partial("_derp")
//abbreviated
<input type="button" value="Derpina" onclick="derpinski()" id="derpButton" />
//abbreviated
<div id="spinner" style="display: none;">
    <img src="../images/loading.gif">
</div>
```

**_derp.cshtml**

```
<div>
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("DoTheDerp", "Derp", null, new AjaxOptions()
        {
            LoadingElementId = "spinner",
            OnBegin = "DerpBegin", 
            OnComplete = "DerpComplete"
        }, new {id = "theDerpForm"}))
    {
        //abbreviated stuff
    }
</div>
```

**derp.js**

```
function derpinski()
{
    //abberviated
    $("#theDerpForm").submit();
}

function DerpBegin()
{
    alert("begin");  // never fires
}

function DerpComplete()
{
    alert("complete") // never fires
}
```

My "spinner" is never shown and neither are my Begin and Complete functions triggered.  I read somewhere that I need to include the unobtrusive-ajax javascript and I have already done that without effect.  Any help is well appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Use Fiddler2 to see what traffic is going too/from the page. also make sure your .js is being pulled down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to add a comment but my reputation is too low to do so.
Could you please check your derp.js file. There is two curly brackets after function DerpCopmplete() that leads errors in js file.

Comment: Sorry that was a typo, I removed it.  This was not causing the problem though.

Comment: Did you include the "jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js" file?

Comment: Also check **UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled** is set true in webconfig.
You can find more information at [codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/429164/Html-BeginForm-vs-Ajax-BeginForm-in-MVC3)

Comment: yes, both the js file is included and the key in web.config too.  I´m still not getting the events triggered.  However the form is succsessfully posted to the controller, just not the events.

Comment: After some tweaking I found out that I wasn´t refrencing the js file correctly, it is now working.  Thanx  :)

Comment: Could you provide a bit more explanation as I've got the same issue with the OnComplete function not being fired. What was the tweak?